# How can I change my remote git repo from working one to a bare one

Tags: git

I have a working repo on a development server that acts as remote repo for several local machines.  It is also the server that houses the dev site.  So the dev site itself is a working repo (i.e. I can add and commit, but not push, since there is no remote).  All the local machines push to this repo.

I want to make a change and create a bare repo of the site and change the current working, remote repo into a regular repo, just like the local ones are.

So what I currently have, is a website that contains a working repo, to which local repos push.

Essentially, I want to turn the current website into a local repo that pushes and pulls from a new bare repo.  And then change where the existing repos push to.

After my research here, I know that a git clone --bare is probably in the answer somewhere, but what I'm missing is the best way to change the local repos and the server repo to push to the new bare one.

Answer (score 0):

A bare repository in git does not include a checkout. So in order to set the default branch that users will get after they clone, you cannot use `git-checkout mybranch.`

Instead, if you want the default branch to be something other than `master`, you need to do this:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/mybranch
```

Which will update the HEAD file in your repository so that it contains:

```
ref: refs/heads/mybranch
```

This is well documented in the `git-symbolic-ref manpage` but it's not necessarily the first place you'd think of looking.

for more info,please visit [More info](https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/setting-default-git-branch-in-bare/)